# Why doesn't traffic reach to pods in nodes without public IP via NodePort?

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks

I have a 2-node k8s cluster using AWS EKS.

I wanted an external traffic (from the user) to reach pods, so I deployed a service for each of the pods. And I connected a public IP to an ENI for one of the nodes.

The problem is that it wasn't able to reach pods in other nodes which I didn't connect a public IP on.

So one node has a public IP, other one doesn't. And I couldn't reach the NodePort type services assigned in the latter one.

I thought that services can work in all nodes since its a virtual object, so traffic to any of the nodes will lead to the pods via the nodeport I assigned.

I can't use LB type services due to some application architectural reasons.

Does any one know why this is happening?